# Execute Exe file from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, executable

i have one Exe file and i want to integrate it in wordpress.Anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you are on a Windows server? Most WordPress installations out there are on Linux.
2. if yes, then use php [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
3. Could you please explain more what your exe does and what you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: my exe is submitting review to other site.EXE is created with ubot studio.and its on Linux server.

Comment: Then, I think it's kinda impossible, sorry